# Prove that number of parenthesizing is Catalan number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Consider a product of 4 numbers, abcd. It can be “parenthesized” in
5 ways: $((ab)c)d, (a(bc))d, (ab)(cd), a((bc)d),$ and $ a(b(cd))$. Prove that
the number of such parenthesizings of a product of n numbers is the
Catalan number $b_{n-1}$.

I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Your proof is going to depend entirely on what you already know about the Catalan numbers. How did you define them, and have you already proved that they count something?

Comment: I think that [Wiki article on Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) may be useful for you.

Comment: Especially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Fifth_proof) section of the article.