# Associative Law - total number of combinations satisfying the associative law

Tags: combinatorics, associativity

I'm stuck in a problem and need help. Associative law states that

(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)

If there are 4 elements, there are 5 arrangements satisfying the property.

(a + b) + (c + d)

((a + b) + c) + d

(a + (b + c)) + d

a + ((b + c) + d)

a + (b + (c + d))

I counted the total number of possible arrangements for 5 elements, which is 14.

n = 2   #of arrangements = 1

n = 3   #of arrangements = 2

n = 4   #of arrangements = 5

n = 5   #of arrangements = 14

Is there a way to calculate the total number of arrangements satisfying the associative property for n elements?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515386/recurrence-relations-understanding-definition-of-formula, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966233/prove-that-number-of-parenthesizing-is-catalan-number,  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062462/catalan-numbers-bijection-between-applications-of-a-binary-operator-and-dyck-wo. You can find more by searching terms like "parnetheses," "Catalan," and "associative."

Comment: thank you that's the answer I was looking for.